# My bootstrap navigation pills aren't working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set up a `bootstrap pill nav menu`, but for some reason the pills aren't working and the content just all shows up on one page, even though the active pill does change.

```
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills head-menu" id="navbar">
          <li class="active"><a href="#abouttab" data-toggle="pill">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#sponsorstab" data-toggle="pill" >Sponsors</a></li>
          <li><a href="#conferencetab" data-toggle="pill">Conference</a></li>
          <li><a href="#execstab" data-toggle="pill">Execs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#gallerytab" data-toggle="pill">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contacttab" data-toggle="pill">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>


 <div class="tab-content">

<div class="tab-pane" id="abouttab">
<h1>Testing</h1>
</div>

 <div class="tab-pane" id="sponsorstab">
<p>Place holder text</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any Solution?

My head

```
  <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Untitled</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="about-page.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears correct.  Here's a jsfiddle that I used to test:  http://jsfiddle.net/zqpfo8f5/

Are you sure you're properly adding bootstrap's required files?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edited my question to include this information. I don't think I'm missing anything that would affect how my pills behave, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @SofiadelaCruz Try adding all bootstrap files from [CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) and check if  it works.